# Swift 2.1 DatePicker setDate does not set date to current day and specified time

Tags: ios, datepicker, swift2

I am trying to set the minimum date to the current day on the date picker and then for the sake of user experience, set the time to 7pm or 19:00. For some reason it doesn't seem to be working. The minimum date setting works but the time doesn't get set. If I remove the minimum date line, the time gets set to 7pm, but strangely, the date gets set to Monday, Jan 1. Which isn't even this year.

Here's my code below:

```
    datePicker.minimumDate = NSDate()
    let calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute], fromDate: NSDate())
    components.hour = 19
    components.minute = 00
    datePicker.setDate(calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!, animated: true)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can it be that calendar.dateFromComponents(components) is less than current date? Check the time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split that last line into:

```
let date = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
datePicker.setDate(date, animated: true)
```

Then look at the value of `date`. You'll find it is probably January 1, 2000 at the desired time.

Fix this by adding the year, month, and day components to:

```
let components = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute], fromDate: NSDate())
```

In other words, you need:

```
let components = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Year, NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute], fromDate: NSDate())
```

Comment: Even that would set the date to a date that's slightly earlier than the current date since it zeros out seconds and fractions of seconds. What happens to a date picker that's set to a minimum date of `NSDate()` (now) and you programmatically try to set it to a date that's earlier? Does it simply move to the minimum date, or ignore the `setDate` command entirely? I haven't tried it so I'm not sure.

Comment: @DuncanC The code I posted will work as long as the user runs the app before 7pm. That's a separate issue the OP can worry about. This question is about the totally wrong date being created from the incorrect components.

Comment: I'll probably never have to do this since in my app the user is never going to be scheduling any events in the past. However, this works great. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: What's special about 7pm?